# Member variable null after being set from subclass

Tags: unit-test, inheritance

Before I start, I realize a possible solution here is to have InnerClass explicitly reference the testString variable in the Inherited class like such:

In the constructor: `OuterClass o = oc;`

In testIt(): `o.testString = abc;`

However, this mucks up behavior in the VisualForce page. If I was to send my user to a new page as a result of testIt(), testString would be null. As it stands right now, the VF page works fine, but I'm not sure how to write the test correctly.

**OuterClass**

```
public with sharing virtual class OuterClass {
    public String testString {get;set;}
    public OuterClass() {

    }
}
```

**InnerClass**

```
public with sharing class InnerClass extends OuterClass {
    public InnerClass(OuterClass oc) {

    }
    public void testIt() {
        testString = 'abc';
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public with sharing class TestClass {
    public static testmethod void doTest() {
        OuterClass o = new OuterClass();
        InnerClass i = new InnerClass(o);
        i.testIt();
        System.debug(o.testString); //this is null!
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my confusion here stems from the use of a visualforce page with `controller="OuterClass"` and `extensions="InnerClass"`. My desired behavior was produced by having only "InnerClass" as the controller with no extensions specified on the VF page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `testIt()` method is setting the testString property on the instance of InnerClass.

Try changing your debug to `System.debug(i.testString);`

While the separate instance of OuterClass is passed to the InnerClass constructor it is then ignored. You would need to assign it to a member variable and set it as well as the local value of testString.

E.g.

```
this.testString = 'abc';
// where oc would be the member variable assigned in the InnerClass constructor
oc.testString = 'efg';
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Is there anything I can do about the behavior being different when visualforce pages are involved? With the example code I provided, `{!testString}` will render 'abc' once it is set.

Comment: @frontendloader I was mostly focused on the testing code. It isn't clear how the example code would where with `Outerclass` as the controller and `InnerClass` as the [extension](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm). The constructor of the extension should take a "`ApexPages.StandardController` or *CustomControllerName*". Would it even take an instance of `OuterClass`?

Comment: I built a gist of what I originally had, vf page and all: https://gist.github.com/frontendloader/ac4f71f0f7ac777183eb. The second page has "abc" on it if `testIt()` is run first, but is difficult to test. I've refactored my code to function with just `InnerClass` as the controller, and that works and is testable.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add that you are mixing up an important distinction that you need to make in OO programming - the **Class** vs the **Instance**

A class is a template to create an object. It consists of static and non-static fields and methods, a constructor and also static initializers.

An instance of a class is a *copy* of the class, minus all the static content. If it inherits any methods/fields from a parent (virtual) class, then it gets a copy of those too.

So when you instantiate your `OuterClass`, it's member variables are not the same as the member variables that `InnerClass` inherits when you then instantiate it.

Essentially your instances are separate entities and don't share data.

The final piece of the puzzle is static class members - these belong to the Class, not the instance, so if you modify a static member or call a static method, you are calling it on the Class itself, of which there is only one version - never a copy - which is why static values remain valid throughout an execution context.